# my web servie returns a list<myStruct> but the values dissapear?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service function that returns a list with 6 entries, which uses a custom struct. The reference updates on my client side project, but the list returned, while having the correct number of entries, has all the data fields not listed and replaced by one called "PropertyChanged" which is null.

My guess is I'm missing something to serialize it properly, here's my code:

struct:

```
 public struct TreeData
{
    private readonly string text;
    private readonly string parent;
    private string val;

    public TreeData(string Text, string Parent)
    {
        this.text = Text;
        this.parent = Parent;
        this.val = "";
    }

    public TreeData(string Text, string Parent, string Value)
    {
        this.text = Text;
        this.parent = Parent;
        this.val = Value;
    }


    [XmlText()] public string Text { get { return text; } }
    [XmlText()] public string Parent { get { return parent; } }
    [XmlText()] public string Value { get { return val; } }

}
```

the web method (simplified):

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(TreeData))]
    [WebMethod]
    public List<TreeData> getList()
    {
       List<TreeData> myList = new List<TreeData>();
       myList.Add(new TreeData("one", "two"));

        return myList;
    }
```

client-side function:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userName = Session["UserName"].ToString();


        using (ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient())
        {
            Demogs = userinfo[0];
            Agencies = userinfo[1];

            List<TreeData> treeNodes =  myService.LoadSites( Demogs, Agencies, true).ToList();


            DataTable table = myService.getTable();
            myGrid.DataSource = table;
            myGrid.DataBind();


        }
    }
```

So right before the webmethod returns, the list looks correct:

```
        myList Count = 3
        [0] parent= "one" text = "two" value = "three"
        [1] parent= "1" text = "2" value = "3"
        [2] parent= "a" text = "b" value = "c"
```

after returning and assigning to treeNodes it looks like:

```
     TreeNodes Count = 3
     [0] PropertyChanged = null;
     [1] PropertyChanged = null;
     [2] PropertyChanged = null;
```

Comment: Where's the client code? As your problem appears on the client's side, you need to show us the client code. BTW PropertyChanged is an event used for data binding that's raised whenever a property of the client-side object changes. It was created when you added the web reference

Comment: so you're receiving a list with the correct number of entities, but each entity is empty?  A sample response from the service would be helpful.

Comment: I added the function that calls, its the page_load. I noticed that if I look at the service reference in the VS object browser, the treedata class is listed with only "propertyChanged"which is why I thought it was a serialization problem. Or is it expected for that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing Serialization attributes. If you're using WCF webservices you might need to use the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes to specify which members of your struct should be included.